# A word for "insincere/perfunctory advocacy"

Tags: single-word-requests

As in:

> This can be seen as an instance of safe, politically-correct ____ of feminism.

Context: an essay analyzing a piece of popular entertainment in which some female characters does a thing that can be seen as pro-feminist, but the idea was never developed, because it is clearly not the focus of the production, hence the "insincere" and "perfunctory" nature of the "advocacy"

Rephrasing accepted.

Comment: It can't be seen as *an instance of politically correct symbolic gesture/act for ...*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say [**tokenism**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tokenism):

> NOUN
>   mass noun
>   The practice of making only a perfunctory or symbolic effort to do a particular thing, especially by recruiting a small number of people from under-represented groups in order to give the appearance of sexual or racial equality within a workforce.
>
> There’s been a lot of hype around it having a female director, but some reviewers have criticized it as ["tokenism"](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/monte-carlo-tv-festival-helen-mirren-feminism-rise-television-1015037).

Answer (score 3):

You can say the program or character *[pays lip service](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lip-service?s=t)* to feminism, as in this critique:

> Scantily clad in leather thongs, thigh-high boots, and a chastity belt, Aeon is a dominatrix designed to titillate MTV's youthful, male audience. The sexual nature of her presentation suggests that, like other sexualized images of "powerful" women, the series is paying [lip service](https://books.google.de/books?id=TJqFAAAAIAAJ&q=lip%20service%20feminism%20television&dq=lip%20service%20feminism%20television&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2o-y3noHaAhWMDZoKHe7CCP8Q6AEISTAG) to feminism while conveying deeply masculinist attitudes in drag.

The expression dates from 1635–1645 and means “in words only.”

Comment: I think your quote is a fantastic example of exploiting an unavoidable double entendre. But in regard to Feminism, *lipservice* is an unavoidable double entendre, and I personally wouldn't use it because I'm not half as clever as the writer you quoted.

Answer (score 1):

It was merely feminist ***posturing***.

> **Posture**
>
> > 1.behave in a way that is intended to impress or mislead. "a masking of fear with macho posturing"
> >
> > 2.adopt (a particular attitude) so as to impress or mislead. "the companies may posture regret, but they have a vested interest in
> >     increasing Third World sales"

source: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/posture)

Comment: I have never seen "posture" used in such a non-literal way, so I doubt it is very common. "Macho posturing" *is* common, but it is more literal.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **spoof**

In modern usage, a spoof usually involves exaggerated stereotypical behavior. But it also can mean deceptive mimicry without exaggeration. It implies that the deception is intentional and engineered. This doesn't really jibe with "perfuntory", though. Spoofing is calculated.

The next candidate is **gloss**

This is also problematic, because it has some fairly tight technical usages in addition to the rather muddy general usage. But it has been used a fair bit in just this way.

> Some feminists, including Suzanna Danuta Walters, brandish a “red-diaper baby” heritage or some other cultural or sentimental affinity to hint that supporting Hillary Clinton's candidacy doesn't just represent some **corporate gloss on feminism**; it's a genuinely radical position.

Why This Socialist Feminist Is Not Voting for Hillary | The Nation
https://www.thenation.com/article/why-this-socialist-feminist-is-not-voting-for-hillary/

> Apr 8, 1994 - Lamest Panel: ”Bad Girls on Top,” which turned into a smug, preaching-to-the- converted **gloss on feminism**.

What happened at SXSW | EW.com
[ew.com/article/1994/04/08/what-happened-sxsw/](http://ew.com/article/1994/04/08/what-happened-sxsw/)

The main import here is *superficiality* which isn't exactly *perfunctory*, but might be close enough.

The best I can come up with that captures *perfunctory* is *nod to*. But it defaults to a complimentary action, so you have to say something like *merely a nod to* or *no more than a nod to*.  Searching the phrase "nod to feminism" shows widespread usage.

*While perhaps satisfyingly politically-correct, this can be seen as no more than a nod to feminism.*